# How to remove certain text-properties from a list of properties

Tags: text-properties

`text-properties-at` returns a list of various text properties.

I want to remove:  `display (image :type xpm :file /Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/.0.images/ezimage/box-plus.xpm :scale 1.1070588235294117 :ascent center)`.  The image may change, so I'd like a general approach that targets the `display` property and any value that may exist in relation thereto.

I thought I was dealing with a `plist` and I read about `remprop`, but it strips everything in the entire list -- i.e., it makes the whole list `nil`.

```lisp
    (let ((props (text-properties-at 0 OBJECT)))
      (setq props (remprop 'props 'display)))
```

Comment: `remprop` deals with a *symbol's* property list - a concept very rarely used in Emacs Lisp (plausible uses for it are debugging of ELisp code, saving extra information with special variables).

Comment: As for the implementation of such function, you would have to specify whether you want it to be in-place, or to return a copy, what to do with multiple entries of the same property-value pair and whether it's OK to use `(setf (car ...) ...)` or similar.

Comment: Does `(remove-text-properties START END '(display nil) OBJECT)` work for you? though I am not sure about what you want.

Comment: What @xuchunyang said. It's not clear just what you want to do. Use `remove-text-properties` to remove any given properties altogether. If you want to modify one or more properties, see `set-text-properties`.

Comment: Thank you @wvxvw @xuchunyang @Drew @pingi for looking at this particular thread/issue.  I ended up using `org-plist-delete` to remove the pair of PROPERTY / VALUE from the PLIST.  The inspiration for this project was to fix a bug in `org-agenda-highlight-todo` which takes text properties found at the beginning of a string and creates a *new* `" "` space between the `org-mode` todo-keyword and the priority.  I am using icons set with `org-agenda-category-icon-alist` and my particular `org-agenda-prefix-format` leaves the icon right where `org-agenda-highlight-todo` can find it -- i.e., FIXME :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`org-mode` contains a handy function called `org-plist-delete` inside `org-macs.el`

```lisp
(let ((props (text-properties-at 0 OBJECT)))
  (setq props (org-plist-delete props 'display)))
```

Answer (score 1):

cl-remprop deletes a property that is *associated with the symbol* `props` itself. This property list is `nil` already. (And remprop only returns true if something was found+deleted, and nil otherwise.)

In your case, the property list you want to change is the value the symbol happens to be bound to.

The function you search is likely `remove-text-properties`:

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Changing-Properties.html#Changing-Properties

Comment: I upvoted because this answer teaches me about `cl-remprop` and explains why it was not working as I had erroneously expected.  I ended up using `org-plist-delete` to modify the list of properties because my use-case was to fix a bug that comes about when `org-agenda-highlight-todo` copies text properties from the beginning of a string and creates a *new* space `" "` elsewhere that has the copied text properties applied to it.

Comment: If you found the correct solution to your problem there nothing against posting an answer to your own question. http://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer

Comment: I posted an answer 14 hours ago, but there is something like a 36 or 48 hour waiting period before an original poster can accept his/her own answer.